# Using iPhones as iBeacons

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I am trying to get an app to work whereby a phone emits an iBeacon signal and nearby phones are able to detect that in the background and do a callback method. Phone A is broadcasting the signal and phone B is monitoring it in the background and calls a method. Here is the code for setting it all up:

```
var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager()
var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
let uuid: NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: "DCEF54A2-31EB-467F-AF8E-350FB641C97B")!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    self.peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, identifier: "device")
    locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
```

This is the code I am using for advertising and for monitoring beacons:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("Beacon has been found")
    print(region)
}

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    print("PM state updated")
    let advertisingData = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:"device", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: uuid]
    peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisingData)
}
```

As I want all devices with the same UUID, I am not specifying the major and minor, however I would like to get the major and minor of phone B for the method it calls when it monitors phone A.

My problem is that phone A is able to successfully start advertising however phone B does not seem to recognise any devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that sets up the bluetooth advertisement is not setting up an iBeacon transmission:

```
let advertisingData = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:"device", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: uuid]
peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisingData)
```

That code actually sets up to advertise a Bluetooth LE Service with service ID of DCEF54A2-31EB-467F-AF8E-350FB641C97B.  This isn't the same as an iBeacon advertisement which is a *manufacturer* advertisement, with the ProximityUUID (different from a service UUID) along with a major and minor identifier.  You set up an iBeacon transmission with ProximityUUID DCEF54A2-31EB-467F-AF8E-350FB641C97B major 1 minor 1 like this:

```
let advertisingData = beacon.peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower(nil) as Dictionary
peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisingData as? [String : AnyObject])
```

Comment: When I follow your code I get an error of  'Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?' when passing advertisingData as an argument for startAdvertising

Comment: I've edited the code, which I believe will resolve that issue